# Trying to download Gauge on centos7 machine

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

I am trying to download Gauge on my centos7 docker. I tried sudo yum install gauge but get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
No package gauge available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I ran yum clean all and yum update -y before, nothing helped
How can I fix this error and install Gauge? Thanks

My yum version:

```
3.4.3
  Installed: rpm-4.11.3-45.el7.x86_64 at 2021-04-25 11:19
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2020-09-30 17:30
  Committed: Michal Domonkos <mdomonko@redhat.com> at 2020-06-02

  Installed: yum-3.4.3-168.el7.centos.noarch at 2021-06-21 06:54
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2020-10-01 17:03
  Committed: CentOS Sources <bugs@centos.org> at 2020-09-29

  Installed: yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch at 2021-06-21 06:54
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2020-05-12 16:27
  Committed: Michal Domonkos <mdomonko@redhat.com> at 2020-03-12
```

Answer (score 1):

`yum` uses repositories to find packages. You have the default repositories enabled - base, extras and updates. When you run `yum install gauge`, `yum` checks these repositories to find a package named 'gauge'. It cannot find such a package, so it reports an error.

For any third party tool such as this one, you should check the vendor's website to see if they have a yum repo. I found [this document](https://docsgaugeorg.readthedocs.io/en/master/installing.html#linux) from a brief search, and I will assume that this is the tool you want to install.

As instructed in the document, you need to a create a new file `/etc/yum.repos.d/gauge-stable.repo` with the following content:

```
[gauge-stable]
name=gauge-stable
baseurl=http://dl.bintray.com/gauge/gauge-rpm/gauge-stable
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Run `yum install gauge` after adding this file, and `yum` will now find and install the package(s) from this repository.

---

Following up on the comment that the yum repository does not work.

Apparently, the document I found is an unmaintained fork of the Gauge documentation last updated in 2018.

The current version of the documentation is at https://docs.gauge.org/ . According to this, a yum repository is no longer provided for Gauge. The current method is to use a script that downloads a ZIP file from Github for installation. These instructions can be found here: https://docs.gauge.org/getting_started/installing-gauge.html

Comment: i get this failure: One of the configured repositories failed (gauge-stable),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail.
repodata/repomd.xml from gauge-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://dl.bintray.com/gauge/gauge-rpm/gauge-stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

Comment: @chimera_girl Gauge no longer offers a yum repo. Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: is this only for VS or also good for intellij?

Comment: @chimera_girl Only for VS Code, since that's the only IDE listed on the installation page. The Gauge team no longer maintains an IntelliJ plugin, the JetBrains team does that. Seems to have limited features and fairly buggy: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7535-gauge